# Convert from NSString to NSDate (even if you don't know the NSString format)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate

I have an NSString that might contain 5-10 different style dates and times.
I need to convert all of them into NSDates.

Does dateWithNaturalLanguageString no longer exist in iPhone SDK 3.1.3?

I do **NOT** need to convert things like @"last Wednesday at 1 pm".

I need to convert things like:
@"01-Feb-2010"
@"Feb 1, 2010"
@"February 1, 2010"
@"12/31/2010"
@"12-31-2010"

(Every example I've seen requires that you already KNOW the format of the NSString.  I have **NO** idea what format it will be.)

Answer (score 2):

Do you know all of the possible formats? You could always try creating an `NSDateFormatter` for each one, then trying a string until a valid date is returned. That's pretty kludgy, but might be better than nothing.

Comment: I don't know the date format.  But it would be a basic, simple, commonly used one.   In other languages it is just 1 simple function call: date = CDate(string).  Done. Not sure why Apple/C/Objective-C puts it somewhere between "very hard to do" and "impossible to do".

Answer (score 1):

I don't see dateWithNaturalLanguageString in any iPhone SDK version; it was probably an error in an older version of the documentation (the equivalent functionality in Mac OS X was deprecated in 10.4 and never worked very well anyway).

Instead, just try parsing with each of the various date formats in turn.

Implementing natural-language date parsing, particularly in a way that works for every locale, is very hard.  If you need natural-language date parsing in another context, the best I've found is the [Date::Manip](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Date::Manip) Perl module.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use a NSDataDetector as it handles unknown formats really well, see this:

[NSDate detection with NSDataDetector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20418863/nsdate-detection-with-nsdatadetector)